# Are applications with C++/WinRT supported on Windows 11

Tags: c++-winrt, windows-11

With the arrival of Windows 11 as a new OS after Windows 10. Can apps with C++/WinRT libraries built for Windows 10 still be used and supported on Windows 11 without any issues?

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"C++/WinRT application"*. C++/WinRT is a library. It makes access of Windows Runtime types more convenient when writing C++ code. There is no message from Microsoft that would even remotely hint at deprecating the Windows Runtime with Windows 11.

Comment: That's still not a meaningful question. C++/WinRT doesn't decide whether your program runs on Windows 11 any more than using C++ would. Whether your program runs on Windows 11 depends on what your program does, which system services it uses, which assumptions it makes about its environment, and so on. [Feature deprecations and removals](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11-specifications#table3) lists services that are no longer available in Windows 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 11 supports the same applications (generally speaking) as Windows 10, including Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps written with the C++/WinRT projections or the C++/CX language extensions.

See [Microsoft Docs: Compatibility for Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/windows-11/)

The supportedOS GUID used for Win32 desktop applications for Windows 11 is the same as the one for Windows 10. See [Windows version check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/windows-version-check) and [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/manifest-madness/).

> Not directly related to your question, but FYI: Windows 11 on ARM64 adds support for x64 emulation. Windows 10 on ARM64 already supported x86 emulation. There is now a new [ARM64EC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/arm64ec) ABI for ARM64 platforms as well.